# Python sorting algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, function, range

This is a coding algorithm i found in python which does not seem to work i get a name error element line 7 and a trace back line 15

I guess my question is how does the algorithm determine that 1 is the lowest number in my array of numbers

```
def copy_sort(array):
    copy=array[:]
    sorted_copy=[]
    while len(copy)>0:
    minimum=0
        for element in range(0,len(copy)):
           if copy[elememt] < copy[minimum]:
              minimum=element
        print('\nRemoving value',copy[minimum],\
        'from',copy)
        sorted_copy.append(copy.pop(minimum))
return sorted_copy
array=[5,3,1,2,6,4]
print('Copy sort...\nArray:',array)
print('copy :', copy_sort(array))
print('array',array)
```

Comment: You're just expecting us to debug it from scratch? Or do you have a specific question?

Comment: This Question is meant to be closed as it was indentation issue, and someone up-voted it. Really?

Comment: My question would be how would the element be less than minimum if they both start off with the index number [0]

Comment: For me is closed! One upvote on this one? Whaaaat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some error about your indentation and element word, it was element

```
def copy_sort(array):
    copy=array[:]
    sorted_copy=[]
    while len(copy)>0:
        minimum=0
        for element in range(0,len(copy)):
           if copy[element] < copy[minimum]:
              minimum=element
        print('\nRemoving value',copy[minimum], 'from',copy)
        sorted_copy.append(copy.pop(minimum))
    return sorted_copy

array=[5,3,1,2,6,4]
print('Copy sort...\nArray:',array)
print('copy :', copy_sort(array))
print('array',array)`
```

Comment: I need to learn to look more carefully thank you!!!!